# Why i am getting gap between view and scrollview while moving keyboard up in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, keyboard

**I have arranged views like below**

[image]

**I am getting gap like below Why?**

[image]

when view is down it looks good, when i tap on textfield then total view goes up and when i scrool tableview i am getting gap between like below.

this is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var belowtextFieldHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var catViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboard(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboard(notification:Notification) {
        guard let keyboardReact = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
            return
        }

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification ||  notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardReact.height
        } else {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Text fields have a property called `inputAccessoryView`, make sure you are not setting the view anywhere and that it is `nil` when the keyboard is invoked.

It looks like you have one set up.